# Modificando valor do meu IsAuthenticated no AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, validação, angularjs-scope, token

Quando o token for diferente de nulo o meu IsAuthenticated tem que ser positivo,

```
app.controller("HomeCtrl", function ($scope, $location) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    $scope.user = JSON.parse(token);

    if (token === null) {
        $scope.IsAuthenticated = false;
        $('body').removeClass('nav-md');
        $('body').addClass('login');
        $location.path('/login');
        console.log($scope.IsAuthenticated);
    } else{
        $scope.IsAuthenticated = true;
        $('body').removeClass('login');
        $('body').addClass('nav-md');
        $location.path('/');
        console.log($scope.IsAuthenticated);
    }

    $scope.doLogout = function () {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        $scope.IsAuthenticated = false;
        $location.path('/login');
        console.log("chamou aqui");
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

mesmo quando o usuario loga o meu valor do IsAuthenticated fica false. como resolvo o problema? Segue abaixo o meu codigo do LoginCtrl

```
app.controller("LoginCtrl", function ($scope, LoginAPI, $location) {

    $scope.doLogin = function (model) {
        if (model.username === undefined || model.password === undefined) {
            return false;
        }

        LoginAPI.post(model).success(function (results) {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            //Armazena o token no localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(results));
            //preciso que o meu IsAuthenticated fique true antes de executar o comando abaixo
            $location.path('/');
        })
         .error(function (Error) {
             console.log(Error);
         }
    };
});
```

Comment: Pode haver problema com o escopo declarado por `let`. Que tal usar `var` em vez disso?

Comment: coloquei var e não adiantou

Comment: A variável `token` está sendo criada?

Comment: Sim, eu consigo logar perfeitamente, entro no painel. Só que assim que eu logar, quero que meu Authenticated fique positivo assim que logar. O problema que esta acontecendo é que eu logo, e tenho que atualizar a pagina uma vez para ele ficar true

Comment: Então, use o serviço para compartilhar a mesma informação entre os controllers, isto é, `isAuthenticated = true`. Altere o valor da variável no serviço e pegue esse valor no controller `HomeCtrl`. Edit: você vai ter que injetar o serviço em `HomeCtrl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No lugar de `$location.path('/');` basta colocar
`window.location.href = '/home/index';`
Pois como você estara fazendo o login, o primeiro momento a pagina deve ser atualizada e recarregada. Fazendo isto o problema sera resolvido.

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece por que você esta atribuindo valor pela LoginCtrl, o valor tem que ser passado pela HomeCtrl que pelo que entendi e o seu scope principal

Comment: Eu tendo a concordar. Seria melhor construir no serviço LoginAPI uma expressão do tipo `$scope.isAuthenticated = true` e depois usar um interceptador para verificar se o usuário está autenticado em cada rota.

Comment: Isso também é uma opção, fazer algo como um Guarda de Rotas, caso você tenha um ngRoute pode estar fazendo a validação sempre que mudar de rota no resolve{}